# Output the dump of a sniffer to an external file in C

Tags: c, pcap, sniffer

I was creating a simple sniffer, just for fun, and I want to output the dump to a file. Here's the code of the sniffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>

#define MAX_PACKET_NUM 5

int main(void) {

    struct pcap_pkthdr header;
    const u_char *packet;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    char *device;
    pcap_t *pcap_handle;
    int i;

    printf("## Now sniffing on: %s ##\n", device);
    printf("## Max packets number for this session: %d\n", MAX_PACKET_NUM);

    printf("[?] Sniffing...\n");

    pcap_handle = pcap_open_live(device, 1000, 1, 0, errbuf);

    for(i=0; i < MAX_PACKET_NUM; i++) {
        packet = pcap_next(pcap_handle, &header);
        printf("[!] Captured a %d bytes packet!\n", header.len);
        dump(packet, header.len);
    }
}
```

It works fine, but how can I output the dump to a file? I tried using file streams, but I don't really know how to output a function. As you can see, the *dump()* function prints the output on the screen, maybe there is a function to output to a file? Please help me out guys!

Comment: Do you want to write the binary data to the file, or write some kind of text representation (e.g. a hex dump)?

Comment: I wanted to write an hex dump

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `fprintf` function. Use `fopen` to open the file, `fprintf` to write to the file and at the end `fclose` to close the file.

Comment: Yes, I tried with those, but how I can write a function with them? They only accept strings or numbers as parameters and I don't know how to store the dump in a string...

Comment: @jndok You simply have to replace your `printf` calls with `fprintf` calls in your program.

Answer (score 0):

If your sniffer runs from the command line on some version of UN*X or on Windows, and if it "prints the output to the screen" by using, for example, `printf()` (rather than `fprintf()`), then what it really does is print its output to the "standard output".

In that case, you can, on both UN*X and Windows, send the output to a file by "redirecting" the standard output to a file; this would be done with

```
mysniffer {command-line arguments} > {pathname to the file}
```